# Display product attribute in admin sales order view?

Tags: orders, adminhtml, collection

I am using Mangeto 1.9.1

I am trying to display some custom product attributes in the admin sales order view page.
If i have to point it more, i am talking about this page: `www.yourmagentostore.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/3/key/271c3dbb00b40c759098c70844b42e58/`

So there i found a table which display the name of the purchased product.

I need something simple, i need to display below this name the custom attribute.

Here is the code that i found for this tablle:

```
    <?php $_items = $this->getItemsCollection() ?>
    <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
        <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
        <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code is located: `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items.phtml`

This bunch of code is holding the table with the name, price and such of the product. So that's what making me think that i have to add somehow here the code for the custom attribute so i can display it.

The name of the custom attribute is `ext_image`

As i display the custom variable in the product view page:

```
<?php 
$_product = $this->getProduct();
echo $_product->getExtImage(); 
?>
```

When i execute this code in the admin sales order view page it's not displaying the custom attribute.. So guys can you please help me display this custom attribute in this page ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The template file for the "name" column in the sales backend is `app/design/adminhtml/default/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

Working with that file, you will be able to what you are after.

To avoid core changes, i'd suggest creating a module with a layout update

```
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view> 
        <reference name="order_items"> 
            <action method="addColumnRender">
                <column>name</column>
                <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
                <template>module_name/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnRender">
                <column>name</column>
                <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block>
                <template>module_name/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
                <type>grouped</type>
            </action>
        </reference> 
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

You can also attach this override to other adminhtml_sales layouts, using the same reference/action methods above...

`<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new />
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty />
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view />` (use invoice_items reference for this layout)
`<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new />
<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view />` (use shipment_items reference for this layout)
`<adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new />
<adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty />
<adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view />` (use creditmemo_items reference for this layout)

Hope that helps

Comment: you _proberly_ also need to load the product attribute data if it's not already loaded into the `$_product` object  
  
  You can do the following...
`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute()`  
  
or _(may not work)_ try preloading the attribute by setting "Used in Product Listing" to "yes"

Comment: No it seems the `app/adminhtml/default/sales/items/columns/name.phtml` is not the file which brings up the name in `www.yourmagentostore.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/3/key/271c3dbb00b40c759098c70844b42e58/` page column... Please help!

Comment: correct pathname is `app/design/adminhtml/default/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

once you have created your module you should be able to use this to get the required attribute in app/adminhtml/default/sales/items/columns/name.phtml

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('yourattribute')); echo $product->getYourAttribute(); ?>
```

i put it after:

```
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
```

on about line 35.

Hope this helps i spent 2 days trying to get it right.